# find unique number value(s) in a time series

Tags: r

I have two huge columns. I want to find the unique value(s) in the first column then extract related value(s) in the second column. But, sometimes we have to interpolate this unique value(s) in both column. Note the first column is cumulative. For example, I want to find 0.321 in A then extract value by interpolation in B. Based on Intercept theorem answer equal to 1.472. Also, if the unique value(s) are less than min or greater than max in A, just print the first and last value in B.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0.2 | 1.25 |
| 0.21 | 1.1 |
| 0.3 | 0.8 |
| 0.4 | 4 |
| 0.5 | 3.2 |

Comment: [`approx()` / `approxfun()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/approxfun.html) or [`spline()` / `splinefun()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/splinefun.html) may be useful.